# Is it OK to merge pages and make other changes while the site is undergoing AdSense review?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, google-adsense

My website is currently under stage-2 AdSense review.   I have identified some key user experience issues which I can easily fix, however I'm worried that it will affect the review process.

Can I delete an entire page (not post) during this process without it being likely to affect the application process? It wont really be a deletion it is just that I have 2 different pages with individual posts which I feel are to similar and would like to merge the 2 pages into 1 page with the different posts via a 301 redirect.

Apart from the above there are a few other minor tweaks I would like to make, all more minor than major in my opinion.

Should you generally avoid making any of these types of changes while undergoing AdSense review or should it be fine to continue with the above?

Comment: 23 lashes with a wet noodle for you mister! ;-) This is a perfectly appropriate question. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you start using Adsense, they detect that you have placed the ad code on the specific page you sent when signing up, they will

> automatically review your entire site (not just the page that you
>   submitted in your application)

From my personal experience It doesn't matter if you change some of your website content while you are awaiting for the review process, the content of many websites changes everytime and Adsense is aware of that.

If your new content doesn't comply with any of the Adsense policy they will send you an email telling you the problem they have found expecting you to fix it as soon as possible.